# Data frame object has no attribute "plt"

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

I am trying to do some machine learning work in python but i cant plot anything using matplotlib. When i try to run the program, i get the error as shown in the screenshot.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ogdz.png)

Here is the code that i am trying to run. I am using Spyder IDE.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dataset=pd.read_csv('student_scores.csv')

print(dataset.shape)

print(dataset.describe())

dataset.plt(x='Hours',y='Scores',style='o')
plt.title('Hours vs Scores')
plt.xlabel('Hours Studied')
plt.ylable('Score obtained')
plt.show()
```

I have tried to uninstall matplotlib and installed it again but it did not work. Can someone help?

Comment: You are missing an "o" on `dataset.plt`.

Comment: Pandas can leverage matplotlib but it does so through `.plot()`, and you're mistaking it for the common `plt` alias of `matplotlib.pyplot`. This is less a typo and more a misunderstanding IMO.

Comment: thanks @kabanus and roganjosh :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for `dataset.plot` not `plt`.