# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'plt'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#loding data
file=pd.read_csv("students_scoure.csv")
# print(file.shape)
# print(file.head())
# print(file.describe())

#plot the data
file.plt(x='Hours',y='Scores',style='o')
plt.show()
```

and i am getting error:

```
5902 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'plt'
```

How can I correct this mistake?

Comment: Hey. It might be a good idea for next time, literally "pasting" your error to google and search SO. You made a small typo :) [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53312835/10618163) what I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`matplotlib.pyplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#intro-to-pyplot):

> matplotlib.pyplot is a collection of functions that make matplotlib work like MATLAB. Each pyplot function makes some change to a figure: e.g., creates a figure, creates a plotting area in a figure, plots some lines in a plotting area, decorates the plot with labels, etc.

You can either use the df directly to plot ([`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas-dataframe-plot) which uses the matplotlib backend):

```
file.plot(x='Hours',y='Scores',style='o')
```

or:

```
plt.plot(file['Hours'], file['Scores'], 'o')
```